# Loading new json url on button click and updating View in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Sorry if this question already exists but i could not find it.

I'm working on an Angular project, and I have loaded a external JSON file using http. This data is displayed using ngRepeat.

I would like to load the file again using different parameters when a button is clicked and update ngRepeat

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('ResultsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get(searchUrl).then(function(res){
            $scope.markersAll = res.data;     
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.markersAll = res.data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // something went wrong
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="marker in markersAll">
    <h4>{{marker.org}}</h4>
</div>

<select id="Category_Selection">
    ...
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
```

I have tried wrapping the JS in a function an calling it when the button is click, but that didn't work. How can I update $scope.MarkersAll using a new http GET request? Or is there a different way I should be loading this data?

Comment: how many data there will be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: updated to use '`ng-click`' instead of '`onClick`'.

Btw, it's a good practice to use controllerAs syntax instead of binding directly to $scope.

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('ResultsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.markersAll = []; //initialize to empty array so ng-repeat doesn't complain
    $scope.searchLocations = searchLocations;

    searchLocations(); //perform a search on load

    function searchLocations() {
      $http.get(searchUrl).then(function(res) {
        $scope.markersAll = res.data;
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="marker in markersAll">
  <h4>{{marker.org}}</h4>
</div>

<select id="Category_Selection">
  ...
</select>
<input type="button" ng-click="searchLocations()" value="Search" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I still couldn't get the view to update, but then I realized I should be using ngClick instead of onClick for my button.

Answer (score 0):

In your `angular js code` you can try following:

```
 angular.module('App', [])
 .controller('ResultsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(SITE_URL).success(function(data) {
       $scope.markersAll=data;
    });
   $scope.myproject = function(marker) {
      $http.get(SITE_URL?marker="+marker).success(function(data){
        $scope.markersall1=data;
  });
```

And in your `html` code you can add this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="marker in markersAll">
   <h4>{{marker}}</h4>
 </div>

 <div ng-repeat="marker in markersAll1">/*data come using ajax on button click event*/
   <h4>{{marker}}</h4>
 </div>
 <select ng-model="marker">
   <option ng-repeat="marker in markersAll">{{marker}}</option>
 </select>
 <button  type="button" ng-click="myFunction(marker)">
```